# Renew the blob lease if blob.upload takes more than 60 seconds

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-blob-storage, blobs

I know that we can acquire a lease on a blob for 60 seconds or infinite.For the following code:

```
  var account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
  var blob = account.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetBlobReference("container/blob");
  var leaseId = blob.AcquireLease();
  blob.UploadByteArray(bytes);
  blob.ReleaseLease(leaseId);
```

If uploadBtyeArray time varies depending on the file size.How do i keep renewing the lease until upload is completed.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After calling `AcquireLease` you can spin up a new thread that constantly renews the lease just before it expires. Once the upload is complete, you should simply abort the thread which does the auto-renew.

You might want to look at the WazStorageExtensions by Steve Marx, which comes with an [AutoRenewLease](https://github.com/smarx/WazStorageExtensions/blob/master/AutoRenewLease.cs) class (look at the DoOnce method). Internally, the `AutoRenewLease` class uses such a thread to a keep the lease:

```
            renewalThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
                    blob.RenewLease(leaseId);
                }
            });
            renewalThread.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks Sandrino!!..With this method,will the Async upload would be taken care

Comment: Can we have infinite lease on blob.upload and once upload is done can we break it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you can use the .NET SDK in order to do this (it still uses 2011-08-18 if I'm correct). The REST API supports infinite leases starting version 2012-02-12 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691972.aspx

Comment: @sandrino yes, but if the worker processing the blob dies, nobody will ever know to start processing the blob again :-\